# Is there a better alternative to Gnumeric?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

I opened a bounty to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/306449/swap-rows-in-gnumeric). Until someone answers it, I have to assume that Gnumeric cannot swap rows.

[image]

This is an excel, `.ods` file. Suppose column A isn't sorted, I want to sort the entire file based on column A, like so

```
35   24 34 24 23 24 13
34   12 21 34 21 45 35
36   22 24 25 26 14 13
```

I want to sort it like so

```
34   12 21 34 21 45 35
35   24 34 24 23 24 13
36   22 24 25 26 14 13
```

Is there a software capable of doing that in the Linux world? is there a software like excel, like gnumeric, but slightly more powerful, capable of doing some statistics and finding duplicate rows, stuff like that?

Comment: Indeed gnumeric can do that: How To Sort Random Data Found On The Internet Usi…: http://youtu.be/Qn0gc5E9HSg

Comment: @muru great I'll install Libreoffice calc anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/), and specifically within it "LibreOfficec Calc" which is a spreadsheet program.

Comment: I had the entire libreoffice suite, removed it in favor of kingsoft office, if you can tell me how to do it in libreoffice, I'll reinstall it, I never saw such option

Comment: @Fischer the icons for sort in LibreOffice are arrows with A.Z next to them. It's a fairly standard feature and I'm very surprised that gnumeric didn't have it.

Comment: ok I'll reinstall it and get back to you, thank you

Comment: now that the main issue is solved, is there a way to detect duplicate rows? - using gnumeric or libreoffice calc

Comment: Will A be the same or are you looking for the values in B...Z to be the same?

Comment: A won't be the same. D E F G H I would be the same

Comment: I'm not sure. Try searching around for the answer on google